# Some Background remain after Background Subtraction EMGU CV

Tags: c#, opencv, background, emgucv, subtraction

I am a newbie at EmguCV image processing and trying different methods of background subtraction. I came across at the method absdiff and gave it a try but after a bunch of processing, some part of the object seems to be transparent and the background behind it can be seen,[Background subtraction sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpLKJ.png)

here is the part of my code that processes the image

```
            img = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
            Mat smoothedFrame = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(img, smoothedFrame, new Size(3, 3), 1);
            img3 = img2gray.AbsDiff(smoothedFrame.ToImage<Gray, Byte>());//.Convert<Gray, Byte>());
            img3 = img3.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(60), new Gray(255));
            IbOriginal.Image = img;
            IbProcessed.Image = img3;
```

How can i remove those "blank or hollow" space in the image above. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to create a mask with pixels of the truck only. You may have taken away pixels in the hollow spaces with

```
ThresholdBinary(new Gray(60), new Gray(255));
```

Decreasing the lower threshold might be what you need but it might include some background noise too. You can always identify the location of the truck first with a higher threshold (what you've done here) then ThresholdBinary on a previous image in the ROI identified.

```
ThresholdBinary(new Gray(10), new Gray(255));
```

Or you can try `CvInvoke.FloodFill`